# Background image not showing up, when i came back on page across menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, paperclip, haml

When i open page background image showing, but after come back on the page image not showing up in chrome (in safari all - ok)

Use paperclip

In my view (some code on HAML + Rails):

```
#list-projects
 - @projects.each do |project|
  .project{:style => "background: url('#{project.photo.url(:preview_16x9)}') no-repeat ;"}
```

Get this html:

```
<div id="list-projects">
          <div class="project" style="background: url('/system/projects/photos/000/000/001/preview_16x9/franchi.jpg?1392386916') no-repeat ;">
            <a href="/projects/1"> </a>
            <div class="description">
              <h3>Shops number two</h3>
              <h4>Square —
              305      м<sup>2</sup>.</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="project" style="background: url('/system/projects/photos/000/000/002/preview_16x9/franchi.jpg?1392310632') no-repeat ;">
            <a href="/projects/2"> </a>
            <div class="description">
              <h3>Shops number one</h3>
              <h4>Square —
              305      м<sup>2</sup>.</h4>
            </div>
          </div>

</div>
```

upd:

navigation generated by this code (rails, haml)

```
%nav#mainmenu
 %li{class: current_page?(root_path)    && 'active' }
  = link_to_unless_current 'Projetcs', root_path
 %li{class: current_page?(contacts_path) && 'active' }
  = link_to_unless_current 'Contacts', contacts_path
```

Comment: After disable turbolinks gem all work fine. why the turbolinks gem do this?

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051244/turbolinks-with-carrierwave-images-as-css-background-image

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding #{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}

```
#project{:style => "background: url('#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{project.photo.url}') no-repeat ;"}<
```

It's turbolinks gem problem. thanks [core2juan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1662970/core2juan)

Comment: It's actually a chrome bug, but yeah turbolinks should fix it.  Did anyone report it as a bug yet?

Comment: I'll forgotten problem and can't fully description her. Can you?